Showing the PPPoE icon in the menu bar, in macOS Sonoma?
Is it still possible to show the PPPoE icon in the menu bar in macOS Sonoma?
I've searched in System Settings > Control Center, but couldn't find anything there. This could previously be achieved as in the image below:

Maybe there's a defaults incantation that could achieve what I'm after?

You can double-click on any .menu file in /System/Library/CoreServices/Menu Extras and it should appear in the menu.


I've managed to show it using the following two commands (based on this Super User answer):
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy \
  -c 'Add :menuExtras:1 string "/System/Library/CoreServices/Menu Extras/PPPoE.menu"' \
  ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.systemuiserver.plist

killall SystemUIServer

